# MySQL Medoo force datatype

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement, medoo

I'm currently trying to get rows from my MySQL DB in a specific order.

Therefore, I found a query like this useful:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE id IN (130,129) ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 130,129)
```

When I run this directly in MySQL, everything is working fine.

Now in PHP, I'm using the database framework [Medoo](https://medoo.in/).

What I do there is running this query:

```
$asservate = $database->query("SELECT * 
                                FROM tbl_items 
                                WHERE ID in (:ids) 
                                ORDER BY FIELD(ID,:ids)",
                            [":ids" => intval($items)])
                        ->fetchAll();
```

What this query results in, when I echo the last executed query, is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_items WHERE ID in ('129,130') ORDER BY FIELD(ID,'129,130')
```

So the values are entered as strings and that seems to be the problem. The result is, that I only get row number 129 returned, no other one.

Is there any idea how I could force medoo to not enter the values with `'` or how I could force MySQL to still execute the query, even with the `'` there?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here's the code for the `query`-function of Medoo:

```
public function query($query, $map = [])
{
    if (!empty($map))
    {
        foreach ($map as $key => $value)
        {
            switch (gettype($value))
            {
                case 'NULL':
                    $map[ $key ] = [null, PDO::PARAM_NULL];
                    break;

                case 'resource':
                    $map[ $key ] = [$value, PDO::PARAM_LOB];
                    break;

                case 'boolean':
                    $map[ $key ] = [($value ? '1' : '0'), PDO::PARAM_BOOL];
                    break;

                case 'integer':
                case 'double':
                    $map[ $key ] = [$value, PDO::PARAM_INT];
                    break;

                case 'string':
                    $map[ $key ] = [$value, PDO::PARAM_STR];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->exec($query, $map);
}
```

Comment: Would be useful to see the code for `->query()` as it is obviously not vanilla PHP code. But it is probably due to the parameter being assumed to be strings. You will need to make sure you are using a `bindParam()` that gives the correct datatype [see Manual page and example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just edited my question and copied the `query`-function from Medoo in here. I don't think I can use bindParam() in Medoo querys...

Comment: Ok so the auto datatype detection is not detecting that your param is a number

Comment: @RiggsFolly seems like, yes. and the problem is, that it's not a single number, but integer, integer, integer, ....

Comment: Your query can be just used `select()` to generate for that. It's supported for array of ids. Why use `query()` for?

Comment: were you ever able to solve this problem? having the exact same issue..